# Is ConsoleColor available for .NET Standard?

Tags: console, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm creating a class library that targets .NET Standard. I can't seem to find `ConsoleColor` (or `Console`, for that matter). Are Console-related APIs available for .NET Standard at all?

Answer (score 1):

`Console` (and related functionality) can be found in (surprise surprise) [System.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Console/).

While I did try adding that before I asked the question, `Console` could not be found because I was targeting .NET Standard 1.2, whereas System.Console is only available for .NET Standard 1.3+.

Comment: Surprise surprise made my day :)